# How to pass parameter to LEFT JOIN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

** Edited for a better understandability **

** Edit renamed to Document **

I want to get all user Document records with vote records on them by given user, and if that user is not voted for some document records i still want to get all document records without votes.
For egzample:

```
+------------+--------------+------+
|document.par1|document.par2| vote |
+------------+--------------+------+
|    2       | z            | y    |
|    3       | w            | NULL |
|    4       | x            | NULL |
+------------+--------------+------+
```

On Ruby on Rails if i tryed this:

I. firs try:

```
Document.
   joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`v_id` = `document`.`id` AND `votes`.`giver_id` = ?", user_id).
   where('document.creator_id = ?', user_id, .....).
   select('votes.*', `document.param1')
```

i got this error:

```
RuntimeError in UserDocumentsController#show

unknown class: Fixnum
```

II. second try:

```
Document.
   joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`v_id` = `document`.`id`").
   where('document.creator_id = ? AND `votes`.`giver_id` = ?', user_id, user_id, .....).
   select('votes.*', `document.param1')
```

Returns only that records that have votes:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+
|document.par1|document.par2| vote |
+-------------+-------------+------+
|    2        | z           | y    |
+-------------+-------------+------+
```

**So there is missing 2 records..**

** Updated, this solution works **

III. My third try, thanks for help Mischa:

```
Document.
   joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`v_id` = `document`.`id`").
   where('document.creator_id = ? AND (`votes`.`giver_id` = ? OR  `votes`.`giver_id` IS NULL)', user_id, user_id).
   select('votes.*', `document.param1')

+-------------+-------------+------+
|document.par1|document.par2| vote |
+-------------+-------------+------+
|    2        | z           | y    |
|    3        | w           | NULL |
|    4        | x           | NULL |
+-------------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: whats `.....`? You should rename `Myclass` to something more meaningful.

Comment: Ok, renamed to Document, now looks better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will get you the result set you need:

```
Document.
   joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`v_id` = `document`.`id`").
   where('document.creator_id = ? AND (`votes`.`giver_id` = ? OR  `votes`.`giver_id` IS NULL)', user_id, user_id).
   select('votes.*', `document.param1')
```

Comment: Not working. i got this query:   SELECT documents.*
FROM "documents" 
LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`voteable_id` = `documents`.`id` 
WHERE  `documents`.`creator_id` = 1 AND ( votes.giver_id = 1 OR votes.giver_id = NULL)     And no documents returned at all. When i delete giver_id = NULL i got all records with votes.

Comment: You should do `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Comment: Great, but why doesn't activerecord allow substitution inside the JOIN clause? I thought that was fairly standard SQL practice.

Answer (score 0):

The condition clause should not appear in `joins`.

This should work:

```
Myclass.
  joins("LEFT JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`v_id` = `myclass`.`id`").
  where('myclass.creator_id = ? AND `votes`.`giver_id` = ?', user_id, user_id, .....).
  select('votes.*', `myclass.param1')
```

Comment: No, this returns only user records that user has voted on, but if user is not voted on several records they are not returned

Comment: This won't work with outer joins: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:897774300346615341

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it seems not to be not working,
and I found one way that solves this by declaring a string variable and pass "ON" conditions to this string and refer this in the SQL command.

For example: `on_condition = "(votes.giver_id ="+user_id+")"`

And the command is:

`Myclass.joins("LEFT JOIN votes).on(on_condition).where('myclass.creator_id = ?', user_id).select('votes.*', myclass.param1)`

Comment: This creates a potential SQL injection attack vulnerability. If an attacker can find a way to get a string into `user_id`, he could do as much damage to you DB as the ActiveRecord user can (which is likely everything). Always use (?) to substitute values into SQL queries.